# How do I render a page based on chunk.js that provided by a third-party

Tags: webpack, react-router, frontend

Our front-end project is temporarily assigned to a third party for development，different repository but same project, then third party developed one page **B** in the project, with route `/b`, and provide us with a chunk generated by webpack split, that js name is `chunk.b.js`，how can I use this chunk to render the page of `/b`?

For more detail, I will show pseudocode below：

**about.js**

```
export default Class About extends React.Component
...
render() { return (<h1>About</h1>) }
```

**app.js**

```
import About from 'about.js'

const routes = [
  { path: '/b', Component: require.ensure => About }
]
```

Then webpack base route split chunk like `chunk.about.js`, all I need to do is use `chunk.about.js` to render `<About>` in other project.

> We assume two project have same dependencies etc.

In my project, I try to load `chunk.about.js` by script tag, but I'm so confused is how to use `chunk.about.js` to render `<About>`

thx ~ ^_^

Comment: The question is a bit unclear, also can you show us part of the code that is causing the problems? What have you tired so far

Comment: Hi, I have reedited this question,  thx for ur help ~ o(╥﹏╥)o